# Fullcalendar not displaying time correctly inside month view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Trying to implement different views inside fullcalendar, some events are displayed correctly whereas some are not.

Eg: here the time frame for 11.59 pm to 9.00 am gets extended correctly to next day whereas for 10 pm to 7 am does not

[image]

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold for an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: @ADyson That works for me, thanks! Is there also a way wherein I can put a 2 days event only on the start date and not extend it to another day ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If an event is two days then it's two days, surely? Why would you want it to only show on one?? Can you give me a specific example then I can understand? Thanks. I mean if you just want everything to show only on its start date regardless of its real length then you could omit the end date from the event data entirely. But I don't know if that's going to be a clear way to present the data to your users, it will look like the event only lasts one day when it doesn't...why would you want to do that?

Comment: @ADyson : If i remove the end date from the end, my view for week and day does not work, the reason I want this on the month as only on the start date is coz the people using it get confused as the attendances extends to 2 days if its an overnight  shift.

Comment: Ok. You didn't make it clear you only wanted it in month view. I suggest you set nextDayThreshold to a very high value then. What's the latest time an overnight shift can end the next day? Set the threshold higher than that.

Comment: @ADyson : I tried doing that too but the problem I faced was that there are different timings for attendances i.e some people work in the morning, some in the afternoon and so on. There are different shifts of work timings. So I tried setting it to 11.59 pm but the shift falling from evening of day 1 and extending to morning of day 2 goes to another cell. Hence I came up with the solution of passing the end date with the start date and change data for start and end date on different view. Still finding an issue as the data does not refresh on view change. If there is a better way pls let me kw

Comment: If you could provide some code and sample data regarding this I could help you a lot more easily. " the shift falling from evening of day 1 and extending to morning of day 2 goes to another cell" ...I'd have expected that to be suppressed if nextDayThreshold was a high value. And "the data does not refresh"...I can't help with this without seeing how you define the event feed or how you do these customisations of the end date.

Comment: @ADyson : I think I did not set the threshold correctly the first time coz of which my calendar did not work as expected. I again tried setting it to 23.59.00 and it works well now. Thanks for your help! Can you please paste the solution as an answer so that I can mark it for others referring to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [nextDayThreshold](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold) to a very high value - at least as high as the latest time a shift can end the next day.

The documentation for the option says:

> When an event’s end time spans into another day, the minimum time it
>   must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day. Only affects timed events that appear on whole-days. Whole-day cells occur in month view, basicDay, basicWeek and the all-day slots in the agenda views.

Hopefully that serves to explain the behaviour you're currently seeing.

The highest you could set it to would of course be the end of the day: `23:59:59` which should cover every eventuality.